# Webview not loading page - Unsupported profile 4 for video, ImeThread is not enabled

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to load a map in a webview. Map link is [this](http://www.michaelkueng.ch/bcs7gj3/).

I simply load the url using :

```
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

I also tried to load the page in a different thread as :

```
webView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}, 1500);
```

None of the above works.

My logcat shows:

```
07-21 20:37:51.528 18758-18758/com.android.pokemapaarau D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:30] Constructor
07-21 20:37:51.543 18758-18758/com.android.pokemapaarau W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
07-21 20:37:51.544 18758-18758/com.android.pokemapaarau D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
07-21 20:37:53.102 18758-18758/com.android.pokemapaarau I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
07-21 20:37:53.165 18758-19212/com.android.pokemapaarau E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
07-21 20:37:53.226 18758-19212/com.android.pokemapaarau I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
07-21 20:37:53.739 18758-18758/com.android.pokemapaarau W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 18758
07-21 20:37:53.741 18758-18758/com.android.pokemapaarau D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
07-21 20:37:53.741 18758-18758/com.android.pokemapaarau D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
```

Answer (score 3):

Just this line will work

```
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 10 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 10MB
```

You just need to define the cache size which will handle everything you need in this case.

Comment: "This method was deprecated in API level 18. In future quota will be managed automatically", from: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAppCacheMaxSize(long)

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it worked,

```
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 10 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 10MB
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT );
```

It was facing memory issues I guess.

Comment: Re `setAppCacheMaxSize()`: "This method was deprecated in API level 18. In future quota will be managed automatically", from: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAppCacheMaxSize(long)

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me recently and I haven't find a solution that worked for me, but after trying several different things this little change did the work.

```
webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Shubham solved the problem, but there are some parts wich are deprecated.
here is the shorter result,

```
webViewClient = WebViewClient()
webView.settings.setAllowFileAccess( true );
webView.settings.setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
```

The webviewClient = setWebviewClient() is used to force the view in your app